# Using #send_data to send image from database broke with Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, streaming

I have a controller that renders images that has been working in Rails 3.2, 4.0, and 4.1. When I upgraded to 4.2 I started having problems. Here is my code:

```
class BookCoversController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @image = BookCover.for_book_id(params[:book_id])
    
    # We use only an ETag here so that clients will have to check that the image is still valid.
    if stale?(:etag => @image.cache_key)
      send_data(@image.image, :type => @image.content_type, :filename => "book_cover_#{@image.book_id}", :disposition => 'inline')
    end
  end
end
```

When I went to 4.2, I was getting the message `Couldn't find template for digesting: book_covers/show` and the image did not render. Checking the docs for `#stale?` discovered and added `template: false` to the `#stale?` call. That made the message disappear from the log, but the image still does not show. I can verify that the code is getting to the `#send_data` call, but no image is being received by the browser. I also tried adding `render: nothing` but both the `Rendered text template` and the `Sent data` messages disappeared from the log, so I don't think that helped anything.

More info: following is a list of the response headers from production (Heroku, Rails 3.2) where the image displays correctly, followed by the response headers on my dev server (local Mac OS X 10.14) where the image does not display.
[image]
[image]

One more piece of info. In production, the response body starts like:

[image]

while in development, the response body looks like:

[image]

Comment: What is the content body? Your headers look mostly correct (although I'd expect a `Content-Length` header).

Comment: @danthedaniel The bodies look quite different, but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Do the two show different content when read from the development vs. production databases?

Comment: Yes, but it's not because of production and development, it's because production is Rails 3.2 and development is 4.2. When dev was 4.1, 4.0, and 3.2 it worked just fine.

Comment: I just found a workaround, but I don't know why it works. The workaround is to call PG::Connection.unescape_bytea() on the image byte string. This seems to have changed in PG 10. My production database is 9.6 and it does not require that call, but my 10.0 database does (also may have happened when I 'pgdump'ed my local database in order to migrate to PG 10.

Answer (score 0):

PG < 10 defaulted to "escape-encoding" on bytea fields. As of PG 10, the default is "Hex encoding". Dumping the table from PG < 10 and reloading it in PG 10 created this problem. The solution is to pull in each bytea field, apply #unescape_bytea to it, and then store it back into the database